# Chrome extension: context menu for video doesn't work

Tags: video, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a context menu item with `"contexts":["video"]` with no luck. The item just doesn't show up when I right-click on a video. So I tried to download [this official example](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#samples) and I was surprised  to see that all its context menu items where shown as expected except for the video one!

Can anyone provide me an explanation as for what am I missing?

I haven't uploaded any code since the full example I mentioned can be found in its place, this code is supposed to work more than any of my own code :)

Comment: Did you right-click on a `<video>` tag, or did you click on a plugin, such as Flash?

Comment: I right-clicked on the video itself, within the box in which the film is shown. BTW, it was a youtube video.

Comment: YouTube? Unless you've activated the HTML5 trial (http://www.youtube.com/html5), odds are that you clicked on a Flash player, not a `<video>` tag. Flash is an external plug-in. In general, plugins are not treated as a part of the browser.

Comment: Oh, these are news to me, thanks. Where can I find this `<video>` tag in a YouTube page, given that I haven't activated the HTML5 trial?

Comment: Nowhere. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks. I want to have when the extension user clicks on a youtube video, then a context menu of the extension will show up allowing him to send this video details (say, url) to a remote server.