# how to add a right click context menu just on youtube videos by using a chrome extension program

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I've searched and searched and searched for a solution to this but every source I found didn't works.

I know the very basics of Chrome extensions and I made a context menu. However, now I'm looking to make one that involves a context menu which works on youtube video.

Let's say when you watch a youtube video and right-click upside of the video , you see the context menu that I want to add.

How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749718/chrome-extension-context-menu-for-video-doesnt-work. What you're asking is not possible, unless your YouTube videos are always using the HTML5 player.

Comment: oh.. then Is there any other way to make this instead of using extension programs?

Comment: You could try to use the [ActionScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference) to embed YouTube videos in your Flash object, and replace YouTube's Flash object with yours. But I think that it's easier to enter the HTML5 trial to always get a `<video>` tag, that enables you to use the [`chrome.contextMenus`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) API for adding a context menu entry.

Comment: okay I'll try as you said. thank you for your quick response :-)